# Imitate behaviour of "generate_series" with SQL

Tags: sql, generate-series, dremio

I am trying to imitate the behaviour of "generate_series".
My table contains various fields. One of these is "count". I want to output each row as often as "count" because each row is going to serve as an independent object.

Dremio, however, does not support "generate_series".

Does anyone know how to accomplish the given task?

regards
Muffex

Edit:

Table:

| id | name | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0123 | ABC | 3 |
| 2345 | EFG | 0 |
| 3456 | HIK | 2 |

Desired Output:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 0123 | ABC |
| 0123 | ABC |
| 0123 | ABC |
| 3456 | HIK |
| 3456 | HIK |

Comment: Does your database support analytic functions?  Can you include sample data in your question?

Comment: Dremio does provide these functions: https://docs.dremio.com/sql-reference/sql-functions/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate a list of numbers that are "big enough" and then joining.  Assuming 100 is big enough *and* that your original table has at least 100 rows:

```
with n as (
      select row_number() over (order by null) as n
      from t
      limit 100
      )
select t.*, n.n
from t join
     n
     on n.n <= t.cnt;
```

Comment: I am VERY grateful for your reply. The output is as intended.
The caveat is that "count" can differ greatly and performance might suffer under the current solution. If there is no (even) better alternative, I will accept this solution.